# gets() not working as expected

Tags: c, scanf, gets

So first of all I would like to paste my code in here for future references:

```
int dayNum = 0;
printf("\n\nEnter your date(1 - 30/31): ");
scanf("%d\n", &dayNum);
printf("\n\nEnter your note:");
char note[10000];
gets(note);
printf("%s", note);
```

The code is I think self-explanatory and easy-to-understand. However, here is a quick and short explanation from my side. This code just gets an integer input and stores it into a variable and then gets ready to take a string as an input and print it out to the console.

#### What I expect:

I expect the code to run like this:

```
Enter your date(1 - 30/31): <my_input>

Enter your note: <my_long_note>

<my_long_note> //prints my note that I wrote above
```

#### What is happening:

But, what is happening right now is like this(abnormal):

```
Enter your date(1 - 30/31): <my_input>
<my_long_note> //this is an input

Enter your note: <my_long_note> //this is an output
```

As you can see, it takes my note before printing out `Enter your note:`.

Can someone tell me why is that happening? I am not quite sure of what did I do wrong in there.

Comment: Stop using `gets()`.  Never ever use it ever.  It has been deprecated for years.  Use `fgets()` or something else.

Comment: And turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Also we have `gets_s` as the safer version. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your output stream.. That means including a `\n` in the printf, or by manually calling `fflush(stdout)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so after another search, I found this:

Using `scanf("%d%*c", &a)`. The `%*c` term causes scanf to read in one character (the newline) but the asterisk causes the value to be discarded.

So my final code became this:

```
int dayNum = 0;
printf("\n\nEnter your date(1 - 30/31): ");
scanf("%d%*c", &dayNum);
printf("\n\nEnter your note:");
char note[10000];
gets(note);
printf("%s", note);
```

And, it worked.

Comment: Anyway you'll need to flush your output, either implicitly by printing a newline, or explicitly by invoking `fflush`. Or other problems may happen.